# Mi consulta Fetch genera un error que se repite muchas veces

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hago una consulta Fetch a la página Json Placeholder, y en un principio funciona perfectamente, pero después de un tiempo (No tarda siempre lo mismo, a veces son unos minutos a veces segundos) se empiezan a repetir los mismo errores en la consola muchísimas veces (a veces se repiten más de 10000 veces), esto genera que la página se congele y tenga que cerrar la pestaña.

Errores:

- App.js:31 GET https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES
- Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

[image: Consola]

Función que realiza la consulta:

```
jsonPlaceHolder = async() =>{
  let cons = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')// Consulta de jsonplaceholder
  cons = await cons.json() // Transformacion de JSON a JS
  this.setState({posts:cons}) //Guarda la array de Posts en el stat
}
```

Esto lo realizo en el componente principal, App.js.

Comment: jsonPlaceHolder  donde ejecutas eso? el setState hace que se renderize de nuevo , si lo pones en un lugar donde se ejecuta siempre pasara eso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé en qué lugar de `App.js` estás llamando a ese `this.setState({posts:cons})`, pero no hay que olvidarse que llamar a `setState` en el `render` puede provocar que React realice renderizados infinitos. Quizás en tu caso eso esté haciendo que se consuma la API indefinidamente.

Así que lo mejor es actualizar los estados dentro de las funciones de ciclos de vida como por ejemplo `componentDidMount()`.

Eso se explica mejor acá: [bucle en react al actualizar el estado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/346941/bucle-en-react-al-actualizar-el-estado)

Comment: Tenías razón, el error se encontraba ahí, muchas gracias.